# Inequality Induction Proof of $(1-h)^n\le\frac{1}{1+nh}$

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm asked to prove the following question using the process of mathematical induction:

$$(1-h)^n\le\frac{1}{1+nh}$$ for $0\le{h}\le1$ and for all $n\in{\Bbb{Z^+}}$.

I'm really confused over what to even attempt for the base step and beyond, I mean isn't 
$(1-h)^1\le\frac{1}{1+(1)h}$ too obvious?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: what's the matter with something being obvious?

Comment: The base case is usually obvious.

Comment: Haha, I guess I've been doing a lot of more challenging induction questions lately so I'm feeling suspicious about how easy the base step seems.

Answer (score 1):

Proving $(1-h)^{1} \le \frac{1}{1+(1)h}$ is half of the inductive proof. The other half is proving that if $(1-h)^{k} \le \frac{1}{1+kh}$ holds for $k=n$, then it must hold for $k=n+1$. So you start with $(1-h)^{n} \le \frac{1}{1+nh}$, then use that to prove that $(1-h)^{n+1} \le \frac{1}{1+(n+1)h}$.

> Assume $(1-h)^{n} \le \frac{1}{1+nh}$. Then $(1-h)^{n+1} = (1-h)(1-h)^{n} \le \frac{1-h}{1+nh} = \frac{(1-h)(1+(n+1)h)}{(1+nh)(1+(n+1)h)} = \frac{1}{1+(n+1)h}\cdot\frac{1+(n+1)h-h-(n+1)h^{2}}{1+nh}=\frac{1}{1+(n+1)h}\cdot\frac{1+nh-(n+1)h^{2}}{1+nh}\le\frac{1}{1+(n+1)h} \because h,n\ge 0$

Comment: Could I ask where you got the $1-h$ on the right hand side of the numerator of the inequality from?

Comment: In the induction, we're starting with $(1-h)^{n} \le \frac{1}{1+nh}$. We take that as true to then prove $(1-h)^{n+1} \le \frac{1}{1+(n+1)h}$. So since $(1-h) \ge 0$, we can say that $(1-h)(1-h)^{n} \le \frac{1-h}{1+nh}$.

Comment: Oh wait never mind, I was just confused for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ we need $1-h\leq\frac{1}{1+h}$, which is $1-h^2\leq1.$

Let $(1-h)^n\leq\frac{1}{1+nh}$.

Hence,
$$(1-h)^{n+1}=(1-h)\cdot(1-h)^n\leq\frac{1-h}{1+nh}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{1-h}{1+nh}\leq\frac{1}{1+(n+1)h}$$ or
$$-(n+1)h^2\leq0.$$
Done!

Comment: It seems so simple now! Thanks!

Comment: @W. Nguyen You are welcome!